# Typescript edit and continue visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.4

I am using Visual Studio 2015 CTP5, and while running the project I am unable to edit typescript, resulting in the error alert box

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Edit and Continue

Changes are not allowed while code is running.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Edit and continue worked fine for typescript in VS 2013. Is there an option to enable, or workaround for this to work in VS 2015? As it stands, VS15 is too cumbersome to use for typescript development.

Edit: As far as I can tell, this is not fixable at the moment, and the issue is currently on
[Uservoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6926059-edit-and-continue-for-typescript)

Comment: What version are you using? I am on CTP6 and can edit a TS file while debugging without a problem.

Comment: I'm on CTP6 and it's highly variable. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. There used to be no limit and it would compile on save.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm also experiencing this limitation on CTP 6.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the only workaround (or quasi-workaround, I guess) I have found so far is this: [Visual Studio locking files while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123624/visual-studio-locking-files-while-debugging).

They suggest while debugging to break all. This does indeed allow me to edit the code and then hitting play resumes the program and allows me to view changes.

It's not ideal, but it's slightly more convenient than having to recompile the whole thing. Still searching for a foolproof way to get around this without having to do anything else than saving, but this works okay for now.

Shortcuts help ease the pain. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> pauses it so you can edit, <kbd>F5</kbd> brings you back out of it and runs the server again.

I'd rather deal with this than the buggy compile on save in VS 2013. Hopefully this gets fixed soon.

Comment: Nathan - Thanks for the edit. I was a touch sleepy when I tossed that up. I appreciate it.