# (File.Copy) Unhandled 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, overwrite, file-copying

I have a problem with copying files, if file exists in target directory, overwrite it, else do nothing. But I'm getting this error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
The process cannot access the file [PATH]/TaskRepository.cs 
because it is being used by another process.
```

I haven't found a solution for hours even. Looked for other topics on stackoverflow but couldn't figure out. My code is here

```
public void EditFiles(List<string> OriginalFiles, List<string> TargetFiles)
{
    foreach (var original in OriginalFiles)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int index = original.LastIndexOf(@"\");
        if (original.Substring(index).Contains("TaskRepository.cs"))
        {
            while (i < TargetFiles.Count)
            {
                if (TargetFiles[i].Contains("TaskRepository.cs") == true)
                {
                    File.Copy(original, TargetFiles[i], true);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is not in your code (at least not in code you provided). Just read error message and think again or provide other code if you are really sure a problem is on C# side.

Comment: You can use Process Explorer ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer ) and find there the program that locked your file. (Ctrl + F and paste the name of your file)

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll there 2 two of these.  @OndřejKubíček

Comment: mscorlib.dll is library. It cannot itself lock any file becouse it cannot be run as process (in common only .exe files can) so it should be a different process that is locking your file.

Comment: Hey I found, explorer.exe is locking my file. What can cause this problem? @OndřejKubíček

Comment: explorer.exe is Windows Explorer. I know that it can lock folders which it is exploring. But it is weird if it lock the files. Maybe try to close all your Windows Explorer windows and then try again.

Comment: My wrong, actually it seem myprojectname.exe locking my file, My mistake. But how can we figure out this problem? Why is it locking the file? Have you any idea? @OndřejKubíček

Comment: @ÖmerÇiftci - Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try copying the files you want to work with to a separate folder. Visual Studio is most likely the culprit but it could be anything locking the files.

[Visual Studio locking files while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123624/visual-studio-locking-files-while-debugging)

Comment: Thank you for answer but it is already enabled edit and continue

Comment: @ÖmerÇiftci - According to the answer Edit And Continue locks all the files in the solution when debugging.

Comment: You are awesome :) Thank you in advance ,you saved me from this obsession :D it works, I've been solving this problem for hours.

Comment: @ÖmerÇiftci - Just remember the more you do this the more you'll feel stupid so keep going until you figure it out.

Comment: I will keep going, and never give up, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using file copy in the same directory please check this ... or there is another method called copyto you may also use that

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\onefile.txt");
fi.CopyTo(@"d:\anotherfile.txt", true); // existing file will be overwritten
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am trying to copy from C:\\Users\\omerc\\Downloads\\Dosyalar\\Dosyalar\\COMED_EMR\\Modules\\Medical\\aaa.Modules.Medical\\Repositories\\Workflow\\TaskRepository.cs to "C:\\Users\\omerc\\Documents\\COMED_EMR\\Modules\\Pusula\\CoMed.EMR.Modules.Pusula\\Repositories\\Workflow\\TaskRepository.cs" here. I used CopyTo method but nothing changed @agsk

Answer (score 0):

It seems your file is not been copied in to the directory I guess your target path is too long to be discovered